# Inserting an item between two items in a list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to find out how to efficiently insert an element between two elements in a list in Java. For example:

[0, 5, 5, 1]

would become

[0, 5, 4, 5, 1]

where 4 has been inserted into the list.

What is the recommended way to implement this (as opposed to copying every single element into a new list?)

Comment: Do you mean list or array?  If list, singularly linked or doubly linked?  There are slightly different approaches to each, and the only reason I ask is because of the bracket syntax you used to describe the question :-)

Comment: `List.add(int index, E element)` method can be used: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29.

Comment: @Nick with the list interface the implementation doesn't matter. Bracket syntax is used for, I assume, convenience.

Comment: @...@...M.  I'm calling you M.  @M.  Good catch, I'd forgotten all about that.  Been a while since I used Java :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`List<E>#add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) to specify the position at which an element will be added to a list.

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

---

So, following your example (using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for convenience):

```
List<Integer> foo = Lists.newArrayList(0, 5, 5, 1);
foo.add(2, 4);
System.out.println(foo); // prints [0, 5, 4, 5, 1]
```